# XSLT recursion crashes after 1000 calls - how to transform it to DVC style?

Tags: recursion, xslt, stack-overflow, tail-recursion, divide-and-conquer

Here is my function:

```
<func:function name="entry-check">
    <xsl:param name="bunch"/>
    <xsl:param name="history"/>
    <xsl:param name="index"/>
    <xsl:param name="depth"/>
    <xsl:variable name="member" select="$bunch[$index]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vipmember" select="key('member-any',$member/@i)[check-vipmember(.)]"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not($member)">
            <func:result select="$bunch[$history]"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$vipmember">
            <func:result select="pp:tern($history,set:trailing($bunch,$member),$vipmember[1])"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$member/self::cmt">
            <func:result select="entry-check($bunch,$history,$index -1,$depth)"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:variable name="next" select="pp:version-bunch(key('i',$member[$depth]/@from)/..)"/>
            <func:result select="entry-check($next,$history,count($next),$depth -1)|$bunch[$history]"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</func:function>
```

**bunch** is actually a set of nodes, **history** is always true(), **depth** is always 3 when this function is called. **index** = (number of nodes in **bunch**) -1

If **index** > 1000 it fails with error message: detected a recursion xmlXPathCompiledEval: 3 objects left on stack. Only this line fails: `<func:result select="entry-check($bunch,$history,$index -1,$depth)"/>`

I'm using 1.0 xslt processor. Tried to rewrite it to tail-recursive, but result was the same (I exchanged the two recursive calls within the function).

Please, provide some help how to change it so as not crash after 1000 iteration (overall number of iteration is between 1000 and 100 000). I checked some examples of DVC recursion, they were very simple compared to my function, so based on these examples Im not sure if it can be changed to DVC. Any other working idea is also appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that the current version of XSLT is 3.0 and offers `xsl:iterate` https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#iterate as an instruction which often allows you to avoid recursion and stack overflow as the processor knows how to implement it with iteration. XSLT 3 is supported on a variety of platforms today with e.g. SaxonJS for the browser and Node.js, SaxonJ for the Java platform (Java 8 and higher), SaxonC for C/C++ and scripting languages like Python and PHP, Saxon.NET or SaxonCS for .NET.

Comment: It's difficult to reverse engineer your existing code, it would be much easier to work from a specification (or even an example!) of what it is trying to do. It would also be useful to know what XSLT processor you are using and whether changing to a different processor is technically feasible.

Comment: I am using xsltproc (libxslt-1.1.28) command line tool in ubuntu. Are there any command line tools that support XSLT 3 and are backward compatible with XSLT 1.0 code? I got this code after a colleague left - unfortunatelly no specification provided.

Comment: There are XSLT 3.0 processors (https://www.npmjs.com/package/xslt3, https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation12/using-xsl/commandline/index.html) that have a command line interface. XSLT 3 is also backwards compatible with XSLT 1.0 but the EXSLT func extension is not something you should expect to be supported in XSLT 3 processors as `xsl:function` is kind of the standardized way to declare functions in XSLT 2 and 3.

Comment: There seems to be another extension namespace `set` to be used, also wouldn't expect that to be supported in XSLT 2 or 3 processors.

Comment: I think `set:trailing($bunch,$member)` in EXSLT 1.0 is e.g. `$bunch[. >> $member[1]]` in XPath/XSLT 2 and later.